# How to get co-ordinate from spiral

Tags: java, coordinates, spiral

Lets say I have a spiral like so

```
8 1-2
| | |
7 0 3
|   |
6-5-4
```

Which continues to go on to infinity round and round.
In terms of co-ords:

```
0 at (0, 0),
1 at (0, 1),
2 at (1, 1),
3 at (1, 0),
4 at (1, -1),
5 at (0, -1),
6 at (-1, -1),
7 at (-1, 0),
8 at (-1, 1)
```

etc...

Another way of looking at it is that the spiral goes up 1, right 1, down 2, left 2, up 3, right 3, down 4, left 4, etc...

So the question is, given a number n, which represents a place in the spiral, how would I get the co-ords of that place on the spiral?

I know how to do this with for loops, but that becomes inefficient as the numbers get bigger.

Comment: Can't this be solved with a [parametric equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParametricEquations.html)? You can read about lots of different spirals [here](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/spiral.htm).

Comment: I have looked at the second link you specified, earlier, but I do not know how to implement this without using loops

Comment: You have to do a first pass and index the coordinates as you go. That is how I would do it anyway.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono what do you mean by a first pass? Go round the spiral and store all the values? This wouldn't working when n is in the billions.